# Android Bluetooth Ble Prevent Pair Request

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Thanks for check my question.

I used the codes in android developer to make the ble connect:

```
BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
    if (device == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Device not found.  Unable to connect.");
        return false;
    }
    // We want to directly connect to the device, so we are setting the autoConnect
    // parameter to false.
    if (mBluetoothGatt != null) {
        mBluetoothGatt.close();
        mBluetoothGatt = null;
    }
    mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, mGattCallback);
```

But after the codes worked, the **pair dialog** will show up, and I don't actually need the pair work, I only need to connect the client and then send datas(The remote device which I need to connect has been set to "no need pair"), is there any way to avoid the pair call?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The pairing dialog is only put up if the remote device actually sends the "Security Request" packet, indicating it would like to pair. So your "no need pair" setting for some reason doesn't seem to work correctly...

Comment: Hmm, But I true cancel the remote device's security request, cause the ios side doesn't launch the pair dialog now.